# How can I transform this Lambda Expression into SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, lambda

I have a lambda expression that has this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(a.startTime).TimeOfDay >= Convert.ToDateTime(startTime).TimeOfDay
```

But, I have to create a procedure in SQL Server and how should be the statement above to SQL statement?

I've tried to use some kinda 'convert(startime, getdate(),8) but it didn't work.

And I forgot to say that 'startTime' is a DateTime field and I'm trying to compare only the time part (forget about the date part).

Thanks!!!

Comment: If startTime is a DateTime field, why are you calling Convert.ToDateTime on it?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/guerchele/archive/2004/05/04/125899.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TIMEVALUE
(
 @Datetime datetime
)
/*******************************************************************************
 * AUTHOR: Luciano Evaristo Guerche                                            *
 *******************************************************************************/
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (@Datetime - CAST(ROUND(CAST(@Datetime AS float), 0, 1) AS datetime))
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
CAST(starttime as time)
```

Have a look at this for more detail [time (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)